# How to navigate through words in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Actually, the title says it all.

How can I get my text cursor to navigate through the start and the end of each word in a specific line of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tap <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd>. Arrow key: **right** or **left**.